# Adding comments for every row

Tags: mysql

I have a `customer` table. I have a new requirement where I have need users to add comments for every new customer that is added to the system or add comments for existing customers.

I know how to add comments on tables and columns so far. I have referred to [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) for details.

**I have considered adding a new column named `comments` to this table.** What else can I do to implement comments for every customer in `customer` table?

Comment: Will you have > 1 comment per customer?

Comment: No, just one comment for one customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want a separate table for the comments by the sounds of it, so each customer can have multiple comments:

```
CustomerTable
    CustomerId int
    CustomerName varchar(100)

CommentsTable
    CommentId int
    CommentDateTime datetime
    CustomerId
    Comment varchar(4000)
```

Comment: This is helpful. I will see if I can implement this. I will make further modifications to this if I have to and let you know.